# How can I trim away shape with inkscape

Tags: inkscape, shapes, path

I have tried a variety of selection options and combinations within the `Path` menu.  I would like to take these outlined shapes:

[image]

and trim it down to be the intersecting shape noted here:

[image]

I would like to have that shape cleanly displayed at the intersection points, but again this is proving to be difficult.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, the two current answers are both arguably correct depending on how your question is interpreted. Think you should clarify whether you want the closed area only or that plus the additional "extension lines". I've assumed the former and up voted accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

[image: steps to desired result]

- You mark all 4 of them
- You select Ctrl+Alt+C, path: contour into path
- You path: unite the paths Ctrl++
- You draw a rectangle around the interesting space
- You choose path: overlay Ctrl+*

Since I use a german menu in Inkscape, I'm not sure for the proppe names of the commands (contour into path, unite, overlay) but the hotkeys should be the same, all in the path menu.

I just chosed a thicker line width, to make the path effects better visible.

Comment: For support on an English interface you can run Inkscape from a terminal with `LANG=C inkscape`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no trim tool in inkscape that I know of unless there was an update but for your shape you can do this: Select the two circles (make sure the smaller one is on top) then go to the menu Path>Difference. You'll get a donut shape. I've set fill colors in my example so you can see the difference. Then select your triangle shape and newly created donut shape and go to the menu Path>Intersection. Your triangle shape is actually two paths so you will have to join them first. Take out the fill and add a stroke if you need to and you should get your shape.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

To "crop" simple paths we may use Boolean path operators like for example:

1. Select all black objects then choose *Path > Combine*:

   [image]
2. Select both, the combined object and the object for cropping (blue).
3. Choose *Path > Intersection*:

   [image]
4. Select the sub-paths for deletion:

   [image]
5. Delete superfluous segments [image]:

   [image]